# How to access a variable declared inside a MVEL expression?

Tags: mvel

Suppose I write a code like this:

```
public class SomeClass() {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     MVEL.eval("boolean boolVar = 2<3;");
  }
}
```

Now is it possible to access this boolVar variable in the Java code anywhere.
Example: Can I print the value of boolVar using

```
System.out.print(boolVar);
```

in the main method just below the MVEL line.

Comment: @ankur-singhal : Can you help?

Comment: @ankur-singhal thanks mate..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember doing as above, `boolean boolVar` becomes local variable, and `MVEL` cannot compile it also.

1.) Need to pass class object.

2.) Create `boolean` property in class, and assign to it.

Expression to be evaluated :  `MVEL.eval("obj.output = 2<3;", map);`

Please try below code :-

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.mvel2.MVEL;

public class SomeClass {

    private boolean output;

    public boolean isOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public void setOutput(boolean output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass myObj = new SomeClass();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("obj", myObj);

        MVEL.eval("obj.output = 2<3;", map);
        System.out.println(myObj.isOutput());

        MVEL.eval("obj.output = 2>3;", map);
        System.out.println(myObj.isOutput());

    }
}
```

**output**

```
true
false
```